# Filtering querysets for nested models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm making a News App API and I want to create an APIView with comments for a speicific Post that also lets users posting comments for the specific post.

These are my models (simplified):

Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Comment:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
```

And view:

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post=???)  
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

EDIT: I would also like my url path to look like this (or similar):

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('posts/<int:pk>/comments/', CommentList.as_view())
]
```

My questions:

1. How do I create a list of comments for an instance of Post?
2. Is it the correct approach or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url for comments is something like: /posts/**post_id**/comments/

```
# serializer
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = SomeAuthorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text')

# view
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                     mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin):
    queryset = Comment.objects
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

        try:
            self.post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.request.query_params.get('post_id'))

            # Prefetch post object in this situation let you check permissions
            # eg.:
            if self.post.author != self.request.user:
                raise PermissionDenied()

            # remember that permission classes should be used !

        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound()

    # It will filter your comments
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.filter(post=self.post)
        return super().filter_queryset(queryset)

    # It will automatically bypass post object and author 
    # to your serializer create method
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(post=self.post, author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Of course you can simply just overwrite filter_queryset method using ...(post=self.request.query_params.get('post_id'))... but i think you need to check permissions somehow.

Comment: If I try to use this solution I get the following error: "__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". Also I think there is a typo and post_id should be in quotes.

Comment: post_id should be in quotes - yes. Are you sure you use "initial" method - not __init__ ? (also check that you inherit correct classes in the viewset - GenericViewSet... etc.)

Comment: I basically copy-pasted your code and it still gives me this error. Also, I should add that my URL looks like this: path('posts/<int:post_pk>/comments/', CommentViewSet)

Comment: You need to use drf routers for drf viewsets. Implement that and try again - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: Works as intended. Also probably the best method to do this. Although I have found a more simple solution that let's me use a generic ListCreateApiView.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PostDetailView to GET a specific post then have the serializer return the comments for that Post.

```
# serializers.py
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text', 'comments') # Comments field is recognized by the related_name set in your models.

# views.py
class PostDetailView(generics.RetreiveApiView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

Comment: If I use ListCreateAPIView for Post detail it will display all posts instead and make the posts editable, not comments.

Comment: Sorry I meant to use a RetreiveApiView, code has been updated

Comment: The view above will get you a single post, with all the comments related to that post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
class CommentByPostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=self.kwargs['pk'])
```